# DT rows_selected doesn't work with FixedColumns extension

Tags: r, shiny, dt

When using the `FixedColumns` extension in DT, the `rows_selected` doesn't register any selections in `Sepel.Length`

Please see the below example...

Any suggestions on how to get around this would be appreciated.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("x3")
    )
  )

server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$x3 = DT::renderDataTable(
    DT:::datatable(
      iris, rownames=FALSE,
      extensions = c('FixedColumns'),
      options = list(
        fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 1),
        scrollX = TRUE)
    ))

  observe({
    s = input$x3_rows_selected
    print(s)
  })
})


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: issue on [git](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/275)